# Unable to get Facebook permissions: birthday_date, about_me always null

Tags: android, facebook-fql

I have asked facebook for birthday_date,about_me and location permissions of user and friends, but when I query to get these fields, these are null. I have 150 friends in json all have these fields equal to null, indicating that facebook has not authenticated permisson.
Query:

```
        String query = "select name,about_me,birthday_date, current_location, uid, pic_square,sex from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) order by name";
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("method", "fql.query");
        params.putString("query", query);
        response = Utility.mFacebook.request(null, params, "GET");
```

Json response contains following fields null.

```
"birthday_date": null,
"current_location": null,
"about_me": null,
```

I am using following code to login and get permissions from facebook.

```
    Utility.mFacebook = new Facebook(Constants.MY_APP_ID);
    Utility.mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(Utility.mFacebook);

    SessionStore.restore(Utility.mFacebook, this);
    SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new SampleAuthListener());
    SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(new SampleLogoutListener());
    String permissions[]=new String[]{"user_about_me","friends_about_me","user_birthday",
            "friends_birthday","user_location","friends_location","offline_access"};
    mLoginButton.init(this, Utility.mFacebook,permissions);
```

onClick method of button is as follows.

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (mFb.isSessionValid()) {
            SessionEvents.onLogoutBegin();
            AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFb);
            asyncRunner.logout(getContext(), new LogoutRequestListener());
        } else {
            mFb.authorize(mActivity, mPermissions,Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
                          new LoginDialogListener());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get the same result when running your FQL via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you not need to request them using the same name as the permission? I.e. it would look like this:

```
String query = "select name, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_location, uid, pic_square, sex from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) order by name";
```

**EDIT**
Have you tried doing this using a Graph API call? I believe the same information can be obtained via:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<fb_id>?fields=birthday,location,bio&access_token=<user_access_token>
```

If you'd rather not use a graph call have you tried using birthday, location, and bio in an FQL call, perhaps they changed the names of the columns?

Comment: user_about_me is permission name,but not a column of User table, when I try to use your query it says. "error_msg": "user_about_me is not a member of the user table.",

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean now, was checking out this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/. Silly question but, the user that is being queried doesn't happen to not have this data set somehow do they? Also, when you look at the app under privacy settings you do still have permissions for this particular data, right?

Comment: It is possible that some user has not set these attributes, but I am talking about a list of 150-friends. It is not possible that all of them have not set these attributes. Even it did not return my birthday_date.